# How to load Object type data in ListView visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, object, listview

I have a query to load users from Parse server and put them in a list view 
But after loading the users i cant add them to the list, In short what i need to do is put a list of Objects type data in a list view

So what should i do

My Code:

```
   private async Task<IEnumerable<Users>> GetUsersListAsync()
        {
            var List = new List<Users>();
            var query = ParseUser.Query;
            IEnumerable<ParseUser> results = await query.FindAsync();
            results.ToList();             
        }
```

Users class:

```
 public class Users
    {

        public Users()
        {

        }
        public string Id{get; set;}
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to load the data in the list into the ListView? If so, please refer to the following code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the view of ListView
        listView.View = View.Details;
        // Add columns
        listView.Columns.Add("Id", 120, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView.Columns.Add("Name", 120, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
        listView.Columns.Add("Number", 120, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    }

    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Simulated data
        List<Users> users = new List<Users>() {
            new Users { Id = "1", Name = "A", Number = "10"},
            new Users { Id = "2", Name = "B", Number = "20"},
            new Users { Id = "3", Name = "C", Number = "30"},
            new Users { Id = "4", Name = "D", Number = "40"},
            new Users { Id = "5", Name = "E", Number = "50"},
        };

        listView.BeginUpdate(); 

        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            // Add new listview items
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
            lvi.Text = user.Id;
            lvi.SubItems.Add(user.Name);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(user.Number);
            listView.Items.Add(lvi);
        }

        listView.EndUpdate();
    }
}

public class Users
{
    public Users()
    {
    }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I already did this,  but what i really need is to load data from the results query above

Comment: Did you miss return value in your method? Here is a document you can refer to.[Async Return Types (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types)